# How to use locals in terraform to repeat and merge blocks?

Tags: syntax, terraform

I have multiple `docker_container` resources:

```tf
resource "docker_container" "headerdebug" {
  name  = "headerdebug"
  image = "${docker_image.headerdebug.latest}"

  labels {
    "traefik.frontend.rule" = "Host:debug.in.bb8.fun"
    "traefik.port" = 8080
    "traefik.enable" = "true"
    "traefik.frontend.passHostHeader" = "true"
    "traefik.frontend.headers.SSLTemporaryRedirect" = "true"
    "traefik.frontend.headers.STSSeconds" = "2592000"
    "traefik.frontend.headers.STSIncludeSubdomains" = "false"
    "traefik.frontend.headers.customResponseHeaders" = "${var.xpoweredby}"
    "traefik.frontend.headers.customFrameOptionsValue" = "${var.xfo_allow}"
  }
}
```

And another one:

```tf
resource "docker_container" "cadvisor" {
  name  = "cadvisor"
  image = "${docker_image.cadvisor.latest}"

  labels {
    "traefik.frontend.rule" = "Host:cadvisor.bb8.fun"
    "traefik.port" = 8080
    "traefik.enable" = "true"
    "traefik.frontend.headers.SSLTemporaryRedirect" = "true"
    "traefik.frontend.headers.STSSeconds" = "2592000"
    "traefik.frontend.headers.STSIncludeSubdomains" = "false"
    "traefik.frontend.headers.contentTypeNosniff" = "true"
    "traefik.frontend.headers.browserXSSFilter" = "true"
    "traefik.frontend.headers.customFrameOptionsValue" = "${var.xfo_allow}"
    "traefik.frontend.headers.customResponseHeaders" = "${var.xpoweredby}"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to use `locals` to re-use the common labels between both the containers. I have the following local defined:

```tf
locals {
  traefik_common_labels {
    "traefik.frontend.passHostHeader" = "true"
    "traefik.frontend.headers.SSLTemporaryRedirect" = "true"
    "traefik.frontend.headers.STSSeconds" = "2592000"
    "traefik.frontend.headers.STSIncludeSubdomains" = "false"
    "traefik.frontend.headers.customResponseHeaders" = "${var.xpoweredby}"
    "traefik.frontend.headers.customFrameOptionsValue" = "${var.xfo_allow}"
  }
}
```

But [the documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html) doesn't mention how to use locals for merging entire blocks, only maps.

I've tried the following:

```tf
labels "${merge(
    local.traefik_common_labels,
    map(
      "traefik.frontend.rule", "Host:debug.in.bb8.fun",
      "traefik.port", 8080,
      "traefik.enable", "true",
    )
  )}"
```

which gives the following error:

tf11 plan

```tf
Error: Failed to load root config module: Error loading modules: module docker: Error parsing .terraform/modules/2f3785083ce0d0ac2dd3346cf129e795/main.tf: key 'labels "${merge(
    local.traefik_common_labels,
    map(
      "traefik.frontend.rule", "Host:debug.in.bb8.fun",
      "traefik.port", 8080,
      "traefik.enable", "true",
    )
  )}"' expected start of object ('{') or assignment ('=')
```

There is a pretty diff of my attempts at this PR: https://git.captnemo.in/nemo/nebula/pulls/4/files

Comment: What have you tried here? I've not tested it but I'd be surprised if `"${merge(local.traefik_common_labels, map("traefik.frontend.rule", "Host:cadvisor.bb8.fun"))}"` didn't work which is what the docs would suggest.

Comment: Tried something similar, edited question with details

Comment: You need to wrap it in the braces still

Comment: I've tried that (and other variants). Still same issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Terraform 1.x+ you can use a [`dynamic` block](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks) to achieve this

```
variable "xpoweredby" { default = "" }
variable "xfo_allow" { default = "" }

locals {
  traefik_common_labels = {
    "traefik.frontend.passHostHeader"                  = "true"
    "traefik.frontend.headers.SSLTemporaryRedirect"    = "true"
    "traefik.frontend.headers.STSSeconds"              = "2592000"
    "traefik.frontend.headers.STSIncludeSubdomains"    = "false"
    "traefik.frontend.headers.customResponseHeaders"   = var.xpoweredby
    "traefik.frontend.headers.customFrameOptionsValue" = var.xfo_allow
  }
}

resource "docker_image" "cadvisor" {
  name = "google/cadvisor:latest"
}

resource "docker_container" "cadvisor" {
  name  = "cadvisor"
  image = docker_image.cadvisor.latest

  dynamic "labels" {
    for_each = merge(local.traefik_common_labels,
      {
        "traefik.frontend.rule" = "Host:debug.in.bb8.fun",
        "traefik.port"          = 8080,
        "traefik.enable"        = "true",
      }
    )

    content {
      label = labels.key
      value = labels.value
    }
  }
}
```

In Terraform 0.11 etc, this could be accomplised with the following:

You need to assign the value to `labels` like so

```
locals {
  traefik_common_labels {
    "traefik.frontend.passHostHeader"                  = "true"
    "traefik.frontend.headers.SSLTemporaryRedirect"    = "true"
    "traefik.frontend.headers.STSSeconds"              = "2592000"
    "traefik.frontend.headers.STSIncludeSubdomains"    = "false"
    "traefik.frontend.headers.customResponseHeaders"   = "${var.xpoweredby}"
    "traefik.frontend.headers.customFrameOptionsValue" = "${var.xfo_allow}"
  }
}

resource "docker_container" "cadvisor" {
  name  = "cadvisor"
  image = "${docker_image.cadvisor.latest}"

  labels = "${merge(
    local.traefik_common_labels,
    map(
      "traefik.frontend.rule", "Host:debug.in.bb8.fun",
      "traefik.port", 8080,
      "traefik.enable", "true",
    ))}"
}
```

Comment: On terraform 1.x, blocks are not allowed in locals. That results in "Blocks are not allowed here."